# D3.js Chord Diagram works on local server but not remote

Tags: d3.js, coldfusion, cfwheels, chord-diagram

I've got a chord diagram adapted from https://gist.github.com/1308257/1b67569b598525efad854978eced78ee74eec158 .

On my version, it works perfectly on my local box (Apache, CF9) but when uploaded to the main box, (IIS6, CF8) I get "Unexpected value rotate(NaN)translate(390) parsing transform attribute."

I suspect it's something to do with dynamically generated .CSV I'm passing it, or something set server side which is changing the response headers. But the data coming through 'looks' fine...

Oddly, it looks like an error is being thrown in ga.js (!) on the live site too which is.. odd.

The test page is here: http://www.oxfordmartin.ox.ac.uk/labs/chord/

This is what it Should look like:[image: should look like]
Instead I get this [image: Bad]

This is my first attempt at d3, so any ideas gratefully received!

Comment: I would suspect the headers being returned by the different servers you have. Either use the Net tab in FF or use Fiddler to capture and compare the response from the two different servers. Fiddler has diffing functionality built in for this kind of thing. Your content-type on the hosted service is Content-Type: text/csv ; charset=UTF-8 (space  either side of the semicolon) but fixing that didn't appear to help.

Comment: @barnyr - here's a comparison http://pastebin.com/vyKRS474

Comment: There's nothing too surprising in the request headers in that pastebin. I think it's worth doing the same comparison with the response headers from the two servers. The errors I see in my console look to be complinging about incorrect SVG, caused by the numeric values being NaN instead, so it may be worth looking at where you're doing some math on the CSV data, as it looks to be that's where the symptoms are. The other thing of note was that I saw 10 or 11 errors of that type, which is far less than the number of entries in the file, so only *some* lines may be failing

Comment: The first thing I'd look at here is the `data` variable passed as an argument to the `d3.csv` callback. My guess is that you'll see it's null or weird, and you'll know that the issue has to do with how your CSV is being parsed.